# Fetching data from SKULabs API via Google Apps Script

Tags: curl, google-apps-script

I am looking to fetch data from SKULabs via their API. I have a basic connection, but I am looking to pull data using either the 'SKU' or 'Name' variables. How do I pass those parameters?

Their API can be found here. 
https://www.skulabs.com/api/

Here's what I have written so far.

```
 var token = "XXYYZZ";
  var headers =  {
    "Authorization": "SKULabsToken " + token
  };

  var params = {
    method:"GET",
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
    headers:headers
  };  

  var url = "https://api.skulabs.com/item/get?fields&limit=5&sort=&skip=&selector=sku";
  var results = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params); 
  Logger.log(results);
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can you explain about your script? 2. What are 'SKU' and 'Name' variables?

Comment: I am trying to fetch the item details for one item at one time. That's what I am trying to achieve via the Script. 
I am looking to fetch the same using either SKU or Name, these are item details as such. More info on API link.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your question from your replying, yet. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. So I would like to try to understand about it. I apologize that I cannot propose a solution of your issue soon.